# Angular : Convert Object into Date and Moment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am receiving a form value for date in Kendo Datepicker. It comes in as an object.

[image: picture]

1)
How do I convert the following to date?

The following in Debugger still left it as Object

```
new Date(this.editHeaderAddressForm.value.seasonalEnd);
```

2) Additionally, how can I convert it to Moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds**

```
var javaScriptRelease = Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT');

var newDate = Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');

console.log(javaScriptRelease);


> // expected output: 818035920000

console.log(newDate);

> // expected output: Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date.parse method

```
const epochValue = Date.parse(this.editHeaderAddressForm.value.seasonalEnd);
```

This will return date in EPOCH this you can directly pass in to Moment function as well.

```
moment.unix(epochValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get date, and moment with short and simple code.

```
var full_time = new Date(this.editHeaderAddressForm.value.seasonalEnd);

var date = full_time.toLocaleDateString();
var moment = full_time.toLocaleTimeString();

console.log(date);
console.log(moment);
```